# Thumbnail Error The source file does not appear to be an image

Tags: django, thumbnails

I finally got a thumbnail error.
I'm using easy thumbnail
I have this code in my settings file

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '': {
        'avatar': {'size': (50, 50), 'crop': True},
    },


}
```

In my post.html

```
    {% load thumbnail %}
<img src="{{post.image}}" />
<img src="{{ post.image|thumbnail_url:'avatar' }}" alt="" />
        {% thumbnail post.image 300x200 %}
```

post.image works but below two thumbnails are not. 
I have to say I'm glad I'm getting these errors, giving me starting point

```
InvalidImageFormatError at /s/

The source file does not appear to be an image


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    content = FroalaField()
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: what is the model definition for post? is this a third party app?

Comment: @Paulo no it's not a third party app, I will upload my model

Comment: @Paulo heydoyouknow this?

Comment: strange, can you post which django and easy-thumbnails version you have? Also post your easy-thumbnails settings (if any aside from aliases).

Comment: I know I've been trying this since this morning, easy-thumbnails==2.3 I tried updating pillow like it's said here
https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/169 but doesn't work,I don't have anything for easy thumbnail other than the one that's posted up there

Comment: @Paulo any idea why?

Comment: @Paulo I found http://deontics.blogspot.ca/2012/12/easythumnails-source-file-does-not.html but don't know how to install yum

Answer (score 0):

You should install the libraries required to support different image formats, then rebuild Pillow:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install liblcms1 liblcms1-dev

pip install Pillow
```